# При описании блока subscribe не задаются значения для этого блока

Tags: html5, вёрстка, css3

При описании блока  subscribe не задаются значения для этого блока

```css
header{
background:url(images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
color:#fff; 
text-align:center; 
background-size:cover;
padding: 130px 20px 90px 20px;
}
header>h1{
 font-size:3.75em;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; margin-bottom:25px;
  
}
header>h3{
 font-size:1.125em;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  font-style:italic;
}

header>p{
 font-size:0.75em;
}

subscribe{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
 display:table;
}
```

Подумал и понял, что по этому огрызку навряд ли получится что-то понять, прикрепил [АРХИВ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0A_Z0KSZbh6cUhDS0NVOHdDUkU/view?usp=sharing)

Где я проворонил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `subscribe` - это не тег, а класс, поэтому правило нужно задавать так:

   ```
   .subscribe {
       background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
       display:table;
   }
   ```
2. Исправьте в HTML коде `subacribe` на `subscribe`.